# Can't use SharpSvn on IIS Express

Tags: iis, iis-express, sharpsvn, mixed-mode

When I try and create an instance of SharpSvn.SvnClient on my local development system, I'm getting System.InvalidProgramException (SharpSvn.SvnClient..ctor() in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\svnclient.cpp:36). I'm using 32bit IIS Express 8.0 with Clr4IntegratedAppPool, 32bit version of SharpSvn, .Net 4.5, the build targets x86. I have the startup element in my Web.config file:

```
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
            <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
```

After I publish my Web to IIS on a different system, it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This startup flag is required whem creatimg the proces. This web.config file is parsed a bit later.

But I have news for you: Later this week there will be new SharpSvn builds available, with binaries for both .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0. The 4.0 build won't need this flag.

[2014-04-16: The new binaries are finally pushed to our site and to NuGet]

Comment: So, do you suggest I put it into he config file for IIS? Or in the applicationhost.config?

Comment: What puzzles me is that after I clean the bin folder and rebuild the Web, everything works. I have some dlls from the test project there, including a 64bit Gallio, but how does it affect using SharpSvn?